# duplicate and insert a row with some modifications

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to duplicate a row and insert it on the same table with some new values. problem is that my table has around 50 columns so my query looks kinda dumb :

```
insert into DUMBTABLE (
, Col1
, Col2
, Col3
-- 47 rows to go...
 .
 .
, Col50) select 'new_val1'
                ,'new_val2'
                , Col3
                 -- 47 rows to go again...
                 .
                 .
                 .
                , Col50 from DUMBTABLE where Col1 = 'old_val'
```

Is there a better way to dynamically get all the columns, and be able to specify whice ones will be updated with new values ? thanks

Ps : I will run this query via `php`. A stored procedure is not an option at the moment.

Comment: That's the way to go. (How could anyone else know which columns to replace/keep?) However, the main question is why your table has 50 columns? Poorly designed db?

Comment: @jarlh yes the DB is poorly designed and there's nothing I can do about it :(

Comment: If you could use a stored, you could think of a procedure that builds a dynamic SQL to do the job, with some input parameters saying which columns copy/modify. With a plain SQL I believe you can't

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are having 50 variable new_val1,new_val2,...,new_val50. If these variables have value you want the new row to have these value in there respective column otherwise you want to retain duplicate row column value. Based on these assumption please find below code:

```
sql = "insert into DUMBTABLE (
, Col1
, Col2
, Col3
-- 47 rows to go...
 .
 .
, Col50) select " + new_val1 == null ? "col1," : "'" + new_val1 + "',"
                + new_val2 == null ? "col2," : "'" + new_val2 + "',"
                + new_val3 == null ? "col3," : "'" + new_val3 + "',"
                 -- 47 rows to go again...
                 .
                 .
                 .
                + new_val50 == null ? "col50," : "'" + new_val50 + "',"
    " from DUMBTABLE where Col1 = 'old_val'";
```